# Angularjs: filter items in ng-repeat containing a substring

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

So I have a scope variable which is set dynamically:

```
$scope.month = 'June'; //this will be a runtime assignment
```

And I have an array(example) which I have to iterate using ng-repeat:

```
$scope.dates = ['12 June, 2015', '12 April, 2015', '13 May, 2015' ];
```

Here's the markup:

```
<div ng-repeat = "date in dates">
    {{date}}
</div>
```

Now what I want to achieve is that in the ng-repeat loop, I print only those dates which contain the month stored in $scope.month. How can I do this using a filter?

Comment: check example with 'friends' array, exactly what you are looking for https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Really it should be a filter. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass arguments to a filter

```
<div ng-repeat="date in dates | filterByMonth:month"></div>
```

Then you can work the rest out in your filter

```
myApp.filter("filterByMonth", function() { 
    return function (dates, month) {
        return dates.filter(function (item) {
            return item.indexOf(month) > -1;    
        });
    };
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13880/)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution would be create a new array and use it in `ng-repeat`.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat = "date in dates1">
    {{date}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.month = 'June';
    $scope.dates = ['12 June, 2015', '12 April, 2015', '13 May, 2015' ];
    $scope.dates1 = $scope.dates.map(function(item){
        if(item.indexOf($scope.month) != -1){
          return item;
        }
    })
```

Fiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13879/)

Comment: @Tarun. Welcome :) But I would also recommend to use `filters` over this solution.